# Is it ok to have a static property into a repository or it's a bad practice?

Tags: c#, repository

I'm building a winform using MVP in C# and I have a repository which retrieves all the data from the DB but to retrieve that data I'm not using an ID, instead it's a reference(string) inserted by the user, so once the user insert that reference I can use all functions created in the Repository to check data, display some information and populate lists, so the user can select missing info.

Here an example,

Instead of have this:

```
public class DataRepository
{
    private readonly DataEntities dataContext;

    public DataRepository()
    {
        this.dataContext = new DataEntities();
    }

    public Data GetData(string reference)
    {
        //Retrieves from DB
    }

    public bool matchData(string reference)
    {
        //Retrieves from DB
    }

    public bool isValidData(string reference)
    {
        //Retrieves from DB
    }
}
```

I'm doing this:

```
public class DataRepository
{
    private readonly DataEntities dataContext;
    public static string reference{ get; set; }

    public DataRepository()
    {
        this.dataContext = new DataEntities();
    }

    public Data GetData()
    {
        //Retrieves from DB using 'reference'
    }

    public bool matchData()
    {
        //Retrieves from DB
    }

    public bool isValidData()
    {
        //Retrieves from DB
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What is `ref`? How do you use it?

Comment: `ref` is a reserved word... so no it's not ok

Comment: What is the intended use of this repository? Is it going to be used in a multi-threaded environment where `ref` may change? If so then no, it's not a good idea. It *should* be OK in a single threaded environment but I would argue there are better ways.

Comment: It's kind of an ID, so when the user inserts that reference, lets say 'AF3G4', I'm able to get the record that matches

Comment: As `DataRepository` is not a static class I would suggest you don't use a static property to hold the reference. Otherwise you can create multiple instances of DataRepository but you can't set the reference to be different for each one, which makes it much easier to introduce bugs through bad logic. Make it an instance property and I don't really see any harm in your approach...

Comment: Why use static for this? Aren't you going to ever have more than one instance of DataRepository? Might they not need to have different values for ref?

Comment: @user2599135 what `matchData(string ref)` and `isValidData(string ref)` supposed to do? Usually you have repositories with methods like GetAll, GetById, Add, Remove, Update

Comment: Hi James, it's single threaded, you think it's better idea to put it as private static in the presenter(controller)?

Comment: Sorry guys about the bad example with 'ref' I just updated. So matchData(string reference) and isValidData(string reference) are functions that represents some rules on the form and I need to check some stuff on the DB for that, they always need the same value on 'reference' property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about *how* you use this property and how it relates to lifetime of repository instance and number of instances you have:

- If different methods of your repository should accept different values of `ref` then use method parameters.
- If all methods of repository should use same value of `ref` during lifetime of repository instance, then use instance property (and initialize it in constructor)
- If all instances of repository should use same value of `ref` then it should be static property

Comment: In this case all instances use the same value, actually they all depend of it, I thought to initialize on the constructor but the constructor it's instantiate before the user inserts the value, should be ok then?

Comment: @user2599135 do you know this value before first instance of repository is created?

Comment: I dont, first instance it's on the Program.cs as I need it when the Presenter class is instantiate

Comment: @user2599135 sorry, didn't get you. Anyway, if you know `ref` before repository is created, then I suggest you to use `static readonly` field for this value. Set it in static constructor and use it in all repositories